# .htaccess code help in admin folder rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory, admin

i done url rewrite below in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) Rrrrr/core-.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) Rrrrr/core.php [L]
```

All the files in admin folder should rewrite into core-.php
And all other files should rewrite into core.php

But all the files are rewriting into the core.php only.

http://www.konasignature.com/shop/women/dresses - this url working as per second command rule
But http://www.konasignature.com/admin/ - not working. 404 page only

Comment: Add sample urls (that fail to meat the admin criteria) to your question, might help us debug :)

Comment: `^admin/([0-9]+)/?$` won't match '/admin/' but '/admin/1', perhaps you were thinking about a regex like `^admin/([0-9]+)?/?$`

Comment: Those rule patterns only matches URL paths with numbers in them - is that what you want?

Comment: @claesv i need to match for all characters. not only numbers

Comment: @Rob need to match all folders like admin/abc/ and also admin/ folder

Comment: but your regx only for numbers

Comment: Try using `^admin/(.*)/?` and read up on Regular Expressions. I'd recommend you read http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html and test before deploying here: http://regexpal.com/

Comment: whats in your apache error.log ? is it possible for you to post the error and also, are u redirecting the files to Rrrrr folder ?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me !

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*) login/core-$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use $ for this command

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ Rrrrr/core-.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*) Rrrrr/core.php [L]
```